# How can I stop one app in my app

Tags: android

I need to create a app which is responsible for closing the other apps which are currently running in background , is it possible ? Can I want close the other apps ? if it is possible then how ? plz help

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773516/how-to-close-another-app-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the other apps are signed by the same certificate, you cannot do this. The system apps (like Settings, with which you can "force stop" any app) have special privileges that are not allowed for apps written by developers.

I hesitate to ask, but why would you want to do such a thing?