# How to block application launch in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to create an application in Android that will show the devices list of applications and then allow the user to select which apps they want to be restricted access to for a certain period of time.

I am aware there is an Android Application named "AppBlock" but i don't know how this works.

You select the app, the period of time and then it doesn't allow you to open the app.

Comment: please feel free to tell what you've did so far

Comment: So far nothing really I am currently researching methods of how i can stop the app from opening, the setting the time part isn't as important

Comment: do you know how the applications is started in Android ?

Comment: Well the "AppBlock" application is available on the PlayStore and starts like any other app and gives you the devices list of applications, so i am trying to do something like this

Answer (score 1):

You cannot actually block start of another application.
The only way that I see it is possible: you need to save the list of applications Info in your app that need to be blocked with the time when it need to be blocked. Implement a `service` that runs "forever" and detects started applications.
Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061179/broadcast-receiver-to-detect-application-start) about how to do it. On each detection you should check if application present in your database and if the time now says it need to be blocked. If it is - close the application. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773516/how-to-close-another-app-in-android) for learning how to do it.
That is global architecture I think you should follow.

Comment: Doesn't closing other Application need "root" access?

Comment: In its simplest form i am trying to block an application launch

Comment: I didn't tried it by myself. I remember that before some version it was possible and than Google developers closed the option. Anyway it needs much more research than this, I just give the direction of where to start.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it

Comment: It's Plattform Version 22, AFAIK. But even before, it was not easy.

Comment: I need to know how to block an application launch, so how would i go about that ?

Answer (score 0):

To Build App Block u need the following things
1-Accessibity services (AS)2-Forground Services (FS)
BY AS you will be able to stop activity that you have in your bloker list
FS will alive your application context that help to find block app